# Understanding the use of the % operator in my loop (Khan Academy project)

Tags: javascript

I hope I have come to the right place. I am currently doing a project on Khan academy where I need to use the % operator to create a loop of books for my bookshelf. I have only managed to get so far but I am stuck on how to get my list of books to automatically go to the next shelf after a certain number.

Apologies if I am not being clear but hopefully with the code and images I have provided, it makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

[Bookshelf Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLl7a.png)
[Bookshelf Project Instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9hUc.png)

Project Code:

```js
//array of objects for books
var book = [
    {title: "The Giver",
    author: "Jamie",
    stars: 4,
    color: color(156, 24, 222),
    rec: true
    },
    {title: "Lord of the Rings",
    author: "Mr Rings",
    stars: 5,
    color: color(222, 24, 97),
    rec: true
    },
    {title: "Lord of the Flies",
    author: "Mr Flies",
    stars: 2,
    color: color(222, 24, 215),
    rec: false
    },
    {title: "Grapes of Wrath",
    author: "Mr Grapes",
    stars: 3,
    color: color(34, 133, 19),
    rec: true
    }
];


// draw shelf
fill(173, 117, 33);
rect(0, 120, width, 10);


// loop of books
for (var i = 0; i < book.length; i++) {
    fill(book[i].color);
    rect(100 * i + 5, 20, 90, 100);
    fill(240, 228, 240);
    text(book[i].author, 100 * i + 10, 85, 70, 100);
    text(book[i].title, 100 * i + 10, 30, 70, 100);
    for (var s = 0; s < book[i].stars; s++) {
    image(getImage("cute/Star"), 5 + s * 15 + i * 100, 90, 20, 30);    
    }
    if(book[i].rec === true) {
    image(getImage("creatures/Winston"), i * 100 + 75, 25, 15, 15);       
    } else {
    image(getImage("creatures/OhNoes"), i * 100 + 75, 25, 15, 15);   
    }
    fill(173, 117, 33);
    rect(0, 120 + i * 100, width, 10);
}›
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript as many other programming languages uses % (Percentage sign) as an operator called [Remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()#Remainder_()), it will return the remainder after division of one number by another

Examples:

```
2 % 4 //-> 0
4 % 4 //-> 0
5 % 4 //-> 1
6 % 4 //-> 2
8 % 4 //-> 0
9 % 4 //-> 1
10 % 4 //-> 2
```

In the assignment he asks you to add more shelves down the canvas, and it's apparent that the shelve contains only four books, you can use `%` for determining the index of any book in each shelve inside the loop, as I mentioned in the examples above, if you're using the image index as the left-hand of the operation and the length of books as the right-hand, you will know which is the first book in the left in each shelve hence you can count its location in the canvas

```
(index + 1) % 4 // Add one to index because computer starts counting from 0
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice, I know I could probably find the answer somehow myself but I am in the early stages of learning so its much easier to ask on here. Thank you again.